# Hibernate query with an alias

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

What's wrong with

```
session.createCriteria(Composed.class, "main")
.createAlias("main.id.branch", "b1")
.add(Restrictions.eq("b1.owner", user))
.list();
```

? The corresponding HQL works fine

```
String hql = "select main from Composed as main"
        + "left join main.id.branch as b1 where b1.owner = ?";
session.createQuery(hql)
.setInteger(0, user.id().intValue())
.list();
```

From the Criteria, **Hibernate creates no join** and uses `where b1x1_.owner_id=?`, but there's no `b1x1_` anywhere, so it fails with "could not prepare statement".

The classes are rather trivial

```
@Entity class Composed {
    @Id ComposedId id; // also tried @EmbeddedId
    ... irrelevant stuff
}

@Embeddable class ComposedId {
    @ManyToOne(optional=false) Branch branch;
    ... irrelevant stuff
}

@Entity class Branch {
    @Id Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false) User owner;
    ... irrelevant stuff
}

@Entity class User {
    @Id Integer id;
    ... irrelevant stuff
}
```

## Update

I've finally created an [SSCCE](https://github.com/Maaartinus/bug-demo/blob/master/src/main/HHH10442.java) and filed an [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10442?jql=project%20%3D%20HHH). Sorry for the confusing question, without the SSCCE, it's rather hard to reproduce.

Comment: Not sure, but did you try creating alias in steps? say first for main.id=x1 then x1.branch= x2 and so on.?

Comment: @Forkmohit Now, I did. IMHO there's no need for aliasing main.id as it's embedded, but I've tried it. I've also tried to create the alias for main.id only and whatelse.

Comment: Could you try `Restrictions.eq("b1.owner.id", user.id().intValue())`? Could you also share whole generated SQL and error message.

Comment: Aren't you missing mapping on `Use owner;`[sic] field in `Branch` class?

Comment: What hibernate version are you using? With your annotated classes in the question, I cannot even create a SessionFactory. I get the following exception:  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1499)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I'm afraid I made quite a few mistakes when extracting this example from my real code. I fixed it now. And no, there's missing mapping problem (quite a few other queries work well).

Comment: @NathanKummer See my above comment. I'm using 5.0.4., but the problem was probably missing `@Id` on `Integer id`. I'll try to create an self-contained executable example when I get some spare time (for now, I'm sticking with the HQL).

Comment: Yes. I made changes to the model the way that I thought it ought to look and as soon as I did that, both the criteria and the hql worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try but maybe creating two aliases with left join helps you. I mean this:

```
session.createCriteria(Composed.class, "main")
   .createAlias("main.id", "id1", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
   .createAlias("id1.branch", "b1", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
   .add(Restrictions.eq("b1.owner", user))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need a sub criteria for the join instead of an alias since `Branch` is a mapped `Entity`.

```
session.createCriteria(Composed.class, "main")
    .createCriteria("main.id.branch", "b1")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("b1.owner", user))
    .list();
```

Comment: No idea, if this really helps, and no time to try it out now, but the bounty is going to expire soon. Could you elaborate on the reason why I need sub criteria?

Comment: You said `Hibernate creates no join` which is the result of you not instructing hibernate to do so. When you create a sub criteria you force hibernate to create a join. I have no experience yet with `embeddable` but i assume they behave the same as `components`. I did not tested it either, but wrote down on how I do it. Don't rush for the bounty, if it expires it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. I guess, in the meantime I've tried all possibilities. I regret having used composed id, as Hibernate is broken on this side. I've even tried JPA with hibernate-jpamodelgen, but it generates nothing for my `ComposedId`, so I'm lost again. Maybe it's because of me using a static nested class.